# Do macros assigned to Razer keyboards work across different computers?

Tags: keyboard, razer-keyboard, razer-synapse

Let's say I connect a Razer Blackwidow v3 Pro keyboard to a computer and use Razer Synapse to [assign a macro to my keyboard](https://mysupport.razer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5549/%7E/how-to-assign-a-macro-to-a-razer-keyboard). Will that macro still work if I connect my keyboard to a different computer?

Comment: It should since the keyboard likely has a very small amount of storage to save the RGB profile

Answer (score 2):

Razer profiles and macros are stored on the Razer device, keyboard or mouse.

For example, see the article
[How to switch profiles on the Razer keyboard](https://mysupport.razer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5419/%7E/how-to-switch-profiles-on-the-razer-keyboard),
section "Switch prof‌iles saved on the Onboard Memory",

In most cases the onboard memory is enough for the execution
of the macros, especially when mapping one key to another
or to a string of characters.

However, in more complex cases they might not have effect if the
Razer software is not installed on the target computer.
(Warning : I have never used Razer keyboards.)

I have used similar keyboards, not of Razer, where the
macros could have called up Windows programs. I don't know
if Razer macros have this capability, but such macros will need
the Razer software to function.

Comment: If the macro is stored to onboard memory, then Synapse is not required. Hence the wording in step 6 `Ensure Razer Synapse is not running in the background.` in the "Switch profiles saved on the Onboard Memory" section.

Comment: @MC10: Do you have first-hand knowledge of it? The text seems ambiguous as it may also be explained as avoiding having two running copies of the software.

Comment: @harrymc - I can confirm the keyboard shortcut works on a machine without Synapse

Comment: @Ramhound: Noted. I improved my answer.